# Getting HTML element class from AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have block of AngularJS code that looks like the following:

```
<ion-list can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" simplify-item>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:orange;">
      Hello
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The directives come from the ionic framework. Still, I am trying to add my own directive to this. I want to set a CSS property via an attribute called "simplify-item". My directive to make this happen looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('simplifyItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(element) {
      console.log('linking element');
      if (element === null) {
        console.log('element is null');
      } else {
    var result = element.hasClass('item-complex');
    if (result === null) {
      console.log('result is null.');
    } else {
      console.log('Sweet!');
    }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

When the line `var result = element.hasClass('item-complex');` gets executed, I get an exception. The exception says:

```
undefined is not a function
```

I don't understand why I can't do this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
myApp.directive('simplifyItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope , iElement, iAttrs) {
     var element = iElement;
      console.log('linking element');
      if (element === null) {
        console.log('element is null');
      } else {
    var result = element.hasClass('item-complex');
    if (result === null) {
      console.log('result is null.');
    } else {
      console.log('Sweet!');
    }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

explanation from angular docs

Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the link option. link takes a function with the following signature, function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... } where:

- **scope** is an Angular scope object.
- **element** is the jqLite-wrapped  element that this directive matches.
- **attrs** is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding
  attribute values.